# UITableView's custom delegate doesn't get called when displayed from UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, uipopovercontroller

Hoping someone had to solve related issues .. this is driving me nuts :/

My UITableViewController implements a custom delegate method:
.h

```
@protocol folderDelegate
@required
- (void)folderViewDidSelectPlan:(NSString*)planId;
@end

@interface FolderViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation FolderViewController
@synthesize delegate;
```

...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    NSDictionary *row = [self->resultsPlan objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(folderViewDidSelectPlan:)]) {
        [delegate folderViewDidSelectPlan:[row objectForKey:@"id"]];
    }
}
```

In my iPad's MainView I'm displaying this UITableView via UIPopoverController:

```
@interface ProjectViewController ()<folderDelegate>
```

...

```
- (void) selectPlan:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender
{
    if([self->popoverSelectPlanController isPopoverVisible]){
        [self->popoverSelectPlanController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }

    FolderViewController *folder = [[FolderViewController alloc]     initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped withInstallation:self->_installationId withProjectId:self->_projectId withParentFolderId:@""];
    folder.delegate = self;

    UINavigationController *folderNavView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:folder];

    self->popoverSelectPlanController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:folderNavView];
    [self->popoverSelectPlanController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

And handling the delegate via:

```
- (void) folderViewDidSelectPlan:(NSString *)planId
{
    NSLog(@"called");
}
```

However, folderViewDidSelectPlan never get's called - I'm really stuck here, hope anyone has an idea how to solve this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you declare delegate property in UITableViewController.h file? You should call it as self.delegate or _delegate instead of [delegate folderViewDidSelectPlan:[row objectForKey:@"id"]];

Comment: Hi @greg, thanks - forgot to post this .. I've declared it as '@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;' - and of course '@synthesize delegate;' in .m File.

Comment: try use self.delegate instead of in your UITableViewController.m file every time instead of just delegate.

Comment: Thanks @Greg - tried it, but it doesn't make any difference :/

Comment: Thanks @Cy-4AH, just solved this issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change declaration of the property to:

```
@property (assign) id<folderDelegate> delegate;
```

And also use self.delegate instead of in your UITableViewController.m file every time instead of just delegate.
If you don't have to support iOS4 or less remove synthesise from UITableViewController.m.

Comment: Thanks @Greg - this did help, though I made a horrible mistake by myself .. my TableView did call itself with "parent folder id" = "current folder" id when selecting a folder (I'm displaying folders and files, delegate should call when selecting a file), so I had to pass the delegates through. Thanks for your help again!